# Better understanding of the meaning of implication in equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

While solving this equation
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}+x=1$$
I started to have some doubts about my real logical understanding of what I'm doing: I will show the steps to try to communicate better what I mean. We know that adding/subtracting functions that belong to the domain of the original equation gives an equivalent equation (meaning it has the same solutions of the first one), so if I want to add $-x$ both sides the correct logical operator is
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}+x=1\iff\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x $$
Going on, I know that is true that $a=b\implies a^2=b^2$, so the next step is not an equivalence but an implication; meaning that the correct logic operator is
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x \implies x^2+1=(1-x)^2$$
Now since $(1-x)^2=x^2-2x+1$, I suppose that an equality is an equivalence (correct me if I'm wrong) so I get
$$x^2+1=(1-x)^2 \iff x^2+1=x^2-2x+1 \iff -2x=0 \iff x=0$$
So, since they are all equivalence and there is an implication, connecting the first and the last I get
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x \implies x=0$$
So the questions are:

a) since an equation is the problem to determine which unknowns, substituted in the equality, makes the equality true, it seems to me, of course wrongly, that we've obtained the converse, that is "if equation is zero then the unknowns are $*$" while, if I've not understood wrong, we are searching for what unknowns make the equation verified, so we're searching for the converse implication "if unknowns are $*$ these then the equation is verified". What am I missing here?

b) In the equation $\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x$ I have on the left hand side a non negative quantity while on the right hand side a quantity that can be negative for some values of $x$; so, when arriving to $(2)$, I should add a condition $1-x \geq 0$ to have a real equivalence?

Thanks.

Comment: “We know that adding/subtracting functions that belong to the domain of the original equation gives an equivalent equation (meaning it has the same solutions of the first one),“. Are you sure? What about the equation $x=-1$. Add $\sqrt{x}$ to both sides to get a second equation. Then those two equations have different solutions.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Thanks for your comment. However, I don't get what you mean, since the equation $x=-1$ has domain $\mathbb{R}$ while $\sqrt{x}$ has domain $x \geq0$, so we're not adding things in the same domain and so I don't see how this is a counterexample to my sentence.

Comment: I see. So long as you’re aware of domains and such then yes you are correct

Comment: "if equation is zero then the unknowns are
∗". Sorry, which equation is zero? Do you mean, “if the equation is *solved by* ∗ then a solution is ∗” ? Which, by the way is a tautology.

Comment: I think your sentence, “if equations are zero then the unknowns are ∗” doesn’t even make sense.. Unless you can explain what you meant by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of dealing with this. One of them is to do what you did: to be aware of the fact that, at a certain step, what we have is an implication which is not an equivalence. So, at the end, when we get $x=0$, we have to check whether or not $0$ is really a solution of the original equation (it is).

The other way has to do with what you wrote in the final paragraph: when we have $\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x$ we decide that, from now when, we will work only on $(-\infty,1]$; if $x>1$, then the equation has no solutions (since $\sqrt{x^2+1}\geqslant0$ and $1-x<0$. And, on that interval, we *do* have an equivalence:$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x\iff x^2+1=(1-x)^2.$$At the end of the computations, we must eliminat all solutions that we got that do not belong to $(-\infty,1]$ (there will be none in this case).

Finally, I dont' see why is that that you assert that what we were supposed to be doing is “if unknowns are ∗ these then the equation is verified”; it's the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, about your "finally..." my confusion comes from the fact that, with only the implication, we must check if the solution satisfies the equation, and this is because we don't have both the directions of the implication. So I tend to think that when we solve in equation we must solve a "two directions implication", and translating it in commong language I conclude (wrongly) that it must be that "if equation is verified then the unknowns are $*$" and it must too be that "if the unknowns are $*$ then the equation is verified". (Continue in other comment)

Comment: I mean, when you say "it's the other way around" it seems to me that we're interested only in one direction of the implication, but then when we "check" the solutions it seems in contrast (to me) to the fact that we're interested only in one direction of the implication (because it seems to me that we're starting from the solution and going back to the equation, like it is a reverse implication, but maybe I'm doing a mistake here: maybe substituting back doesn't mean "begin from the solution and go back to the equation like it is a reverse implication". Is this the mistake?)

Comment: Hope this is a little clearer now, if not I apologize but I'm very confused about this :(

Comment: Now I got it! Suppose that you want to solve an equation of the form $f(x)-g(x)=0$. If you write$$f(x)-g(x)=0\iff f(x)=g(x)$$what you are saying is that those numbers $x$ for which the equality $f(x)-g(x)=0$ holds are exactly the numbers $x$ for which the equality $f(x)=g(x)$ holds. Now, if you write$$f(x)=g(x)\implies f^2(x)=g^2(x),$$then what you are saying is that those numbers $x$ for which the equality $f(x)=g(x)$ holds are some of those numbers for which the equality $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$ holds. (It will continue)

Comment: That's why if you solve this last equation, then you still have to determine which of its solutions are indeed solutions of the original equation. This happens when you have one or more implications. But when you only have equivalences, then what you will be doing will be to determine those numbers $x$ for which the original equation holds. There will be no need to check something at the end.

Comment: It was crystal clear, you are so kind. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 1):

> Since an equation is the problem to determine which unknowns,
> substituted in the equality, makes the equality true, it seems to me,
> of course wrongly, that we've obtained the converse.

Nope. Nothing wrong with that. It just has to be presented properly.

Theorem: $\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x \iff x=0$

Proof: You have already proven that $\sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x \implies x=0$. Now, it is trivial to prove the converse: $$x=0 \implies (\sqrt{x^2+1}= 1 ~~\land~~ 1-x=1)\implies \sqrt{x^2+1}=1-x ~~\square$$